# How to compose functions that return Writer[List[Int], Int]?

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, writer-monad

Suppose I have a few functions `Int => Int` composed with `andThen`:

```
val f1: Int => Int = _ + 1
val f2: Int => Int = _ + 2
val f3: Int => Int = _ + 3

val f = f1 andThen f2 andThen f3
```

Now I need to return also the intermediate results. So I can convert all those functions to `Int => (List[Int], Int)` where the list contains the arguments.

I can probably use `Writer[List[Int], Int]` of `scalaz` to represent the pair `(List[Int], Int)`:

```
val fw1: Int => Writer[List[Int], Int] = x => f1(x).set(List(x))
val fw2: Int => Writer[List[Int], Int] = x => f2(x).set(List(x))
val fw3: Int => Writer[List[Int], Int] = x => f3(x).set(List(x))
```

In order to compose `fw1`, `fw2`, and `fw3` I probably need to wrap them with `Kleisli`. However `Kleisli(fw1)` does not compile since `Writer[List[Int], Int]` is not a monad.

I guess that I probably need a `monad transformer` to make `Writer[List[Int], Int]` a monad but I don't know exactly how to do it. So, my question is: how to make `Kleisli(fw1)` compile with a monad transformer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Writer[List[Int], ?]` does have a monad instance—this is just a case where scalac isn't able to see that without a little help. You can just use `kleisliU`, which is like `Kleisli.apply` but with some type inference help from `Unapply` (which is described [here](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/07/11/roll-your-own-scala/) and in a number of other places):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, Kleisli.kleisliU

val f1: Int => Int = _ + 1
val f2: Int => Int = _ + 2
val f3: Int => Int = _ + 3

val fw1: Int => Writer[List[Int], Int] = x => f1(x).set(List(x))
val fw2: Int => Writer[List[Int], Int] = x => f2(x).set(List(x))
val fw3: Int => Writer[List[Int], Int] = x => f3(x).set(List(x))

val f = kleisliU(fw1) andThen kleisliU(fw2) andThen kleisliU(fw1)
```

And then:

```
scala> f.run(10)
res0: scalaz.WriterT[[+X]X,List[Int],Int] = WriterT((List(10, 11, 13),14))
```

You could also provide explicit type parameters for `Kleisli.apply` or `Kleisli.kleisli`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and reminding me about `Unapppy`. Maybe I will    try to grok it this time.